# Push and pull elements to an array in one query with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoid3

With Mongoid, I'm trying to do :

```
models.update_all({
  '$pullAll' => { category_ids: removed_category_ids },
  '$addToSet' => { category_ids: { '$each' => added_category_ids } }
})
```

I have this error message :

```
Mongo::Error::OperationFailure:
   Cannot update 'category_ids' and 'category_ids' at the same time (16837)
```

I understand the error but is there a way to do those two requests in only one query. I know I can do something like :

```
models.update_all({ '$pullAll' => { category_ids: removed_category_ids } })
models.update_all({ '$addToSet' => { category_ids: { '$each' => added_category_ids } } })
```

but it do two calls and `models` can have changed. I can do something to keep the first value to do the second query but I would prefer to do it in the same if it's possible.

Is it possible?

Comment: No,  you can not do that.

Comment: That's sad. There is no way to do batch queries ?

Comment: No you can do not do different operations on same field in single query but